# Create multiple imageviews in edittext

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-sqlite

So it's challenging for me to create multiple imageviews in edittext and then assign images to it from gallery or camera and then save these images in the database and retrieve it in the same position in my edittext. So what I did is that I created `ImageView` below `EditText` but that is what I don't want. I also tried `Drawable` in `Spannable` of `EditText` which works good in creating multiple images inside `EditText` but then the problem is that I cant save these images in the database and retrieve these to show in the same position as these are part of my `EditText`. I am saving my `EditText` in `html` form in the database.
please tell me some solution about this challenging work. Thanks

The first approach is to create `Drawable` for multiple images but it is part of `EditText` and cant save these images in the database and retrieve them in the same positions.

```
private void setImageinText(Bitmap myBitmap){
    myBitmap = Util.scaleBitmapToFitWidth(myBitmap, 1360, true);
   imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
    Drawable d = imageView.getDrawable();
    SpannableString ssd = new SpannableString("\n  \n");
    d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());
    ImageSpan span = new ImageSpan(d, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
    ssd.setSpan(span, 1 , 2, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    texto.setTransformationMethod(null);
    texto.getText().insert(texto.getSelectionStart(), ssd);

}
```

Other approach is to create imageview in layout and assign image from gallery but i can save only one image in it and the imageview position is fixed.

```
    if (requestCode == GALLERY) {
        if (data != null) {
            Uri contentURI = data.getData();
            try {
                bp = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.getContentResolver(), contentURI);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bp);
                imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                photo= Util.getBytes(bp);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: save every selected image Bitmap in list  and save the list in database and when you want to show  iterate list to show images in Edit Text as Spannable

Comment: can you please explain with codes? I don't understand how can I assign a list of images to spannables?